# HttpPost action method in controller in MVC gives 500 error 'failed to load resource'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I am creating an MVC application in .NET Framework 4.7.2. I have a few controllers in this application and they have all worked fine before. However, with the latest controller, I am getting a mystery bug. The controller is (I have removed methods irrelevant to this question):

```
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
    public class DatabaseController : Controller
    {
              
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult EditTableDescription(string name)
        {
            Table table = new Table(name);

            table.GetDescription();

            return View(table);
        }
        
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditTableDescription(Table table)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // Updates description only
                table.UpdateDescription();

                return RedirectToAction("ViewTables", "Database");
            }

            return View();
        }

    }
}
```

whilst the view the GET call serves is defined by

```
@model MyApp.Models.Database.Table

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditTableDescription";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_AdminLayout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Name)

 
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The [HttpGet] decorated method works fine, serving up the page. However, on submitting the form, I get an error saying *Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500*.

Note that:

1. I have other Controllers/Actions that (so far as I can see) follow exactly the same pattern and work fine.
2. I have tried adding the name of the method and controller to the `Html.BeginForm()` method to no avail.
3. The `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` decoration makes no difference.

For some reason, the [HttpPost] decorated method just does not seem to be seen (and is not called). Anyone have any ideas why this might happen?

Comment: Where is the table parameter in the Post action supposed to come from? Can't see anything named table in the form in the cshtml.

Comment: The cshtml page defines the @model handle as a Table object (first line).

Comment: within your form, there doesn't seemed to be any input named table.

Comment: @model MyApp.Models.Database.Table

Comment: If you inspect the input element that ```EditorFor()``` produces (or whichever element it produces) in the browser, does its html attribute "name" have a value of "Table"?

Comment: 500 is an internal server error. In .NET, it usually occurs when an action method throws an exception. To be sure there are no exceptions, use `try` and `catch` in your `HttpPost` decorated method (and return some error view in `catch`).